# How to change the username in gitbash

Tags: github, git-bash

I am trying to push files into repository using different username and password but it keeps on showing previous profile's username everytime I push

[image]

See `artistic-developers` is the previous username and it should be replace with current username.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you should check what username and email you have configured your git client with.

- To check email: `git config user.email`
- To check name: `git config user.name`

If both show you the new desired values, then you you should be aware of the fact that you push using new account does not mean that the commits were created by the new account. To check the username and email in the history use `git log`.

If you want to change the username and email for the latest commit you can use:

`git commit --amend --reset-author`

If you have more commits to work with, you can use [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Note that changing committer will result in different commit hash and you should avoid doing this for branches you have already shared with others.